# lstdc++ cannot be found by compiling both dynamic and static librarie?

Tags: c, makefile

Now I cross-compile and link my code with both dynamic and static libraries, but the following error occurs: *can't find lstdc + +*(make error 1);
If I changed $LD to $CC, another issues occured: *can't find -lpaho-mqtt3a*(make error 2), what's going on?

change $(LD)

```
$(TARGET):$(OBJS)
$(LD) -o $(OUTPUT_DIR)/$(TARGET) $(OBJS)  $(CFLAGS_OTHERS_LIB) 
   $(LIB_FOR_SRS)  $(LINK_OPTION) 
$(STRIP) $(OUTPUT_DIR)/$(TARGET)
```

to $(CC)

```
$(TARGET):$(OBJS)
$(CC) -o $(OUTPUT_DIR)/$(TARGET) $(OBJS)  $(CFLAGS_OTHERS_LIB) 
   $(LIB_FOR_SRS)  $(LINK_OPTION) 
$(STRIP) $(OUTPUT_DIR)/$(TARGET)
```

I use these dynamic and static libraries to compile links：

```
paho-mqtt3a.so  libjson-c.a  libjson-c.la libsqlite3.so libsqlite3.la libsqlite3.a srs_librtmp.a 
libssl.a libcrypto.a
```

Makefile :

```
COMPILE                    = aarch64-linux-gnu-
CC                         = $(COMPILE)gcc
STRIP                      = $(COMPILE)strip
LD                         = $(COMPILE)ld

COMPILE_OPTION             = -Wall  -Wcomment -Wformat -Wmissing-braces -Wswitch -Wuninitialized 
\
                         -Wbad-function-cast -Waggregate-return -Wmultichar -Wsign-compare - 
Wshadow
                         
#COMPILE_OPTION_DEBUG       = -gdwarf-2 -g 

COMPILE_ALL_OPTION         += $(COMPILE_OPTION) $(COMPILE_OPTION_DEBUG)

LINK_OPTION          = -lpaho-mqtt3a -ljson-c -lsqlite3  -lm -lc -lpthread -ldl -lstdc++ -static

LIB_FOR_JSON       = ./lib/json_lib/*
LIB_FOR_MQTT       = ./lib/mqtt_lib/*
LIB_FOR_SQLITE3    = ./lib/sqlite3_lib/*
LIB_FOR_SRS        = ./lib/srslibrtmp_lib/*

SRC_DIR              = ./src
OUTPUT_DIR           = ./output
SYS_LOCAL_LIB_DIR          = /usr/local/lib


OBJS_MAIN                  = main.o
OBJS_EC_UART_232           = ec_uart_232.o
OBJS_EC_UART_485           = ec_uart_485.o
OBJS_EC_MANAGE_PLCE        = ec_manage_plce.o
OBJS_EC_SOCKET_VIDEO       = ec_socket_video.o
OBJS_EC_MQTT_ANDROID       = ec_mqtt_android.o
OBJS_EC_SQLITE             = ec_sqlite.o
OBJS_EC_STORE_INFO         = ec_store_info.o
OBJS_EC_MANAGE_CAMERA      = ec_manage_camera.o
OBJS_DEAL_REQUEST_LOOP     = deal_request_loop.o
OBJS_PUSH_VIDEO            = push_video.o

TARGET    = ecSmartFire
RM        = rm -rf 
MV        = mv 
CP        = cp -r
LDCONFIG  = ldconfig


OBJS    = $(OBJS_MAIN) $(OBJS_EC_UART_232) $(OBJS_EC_UART_485) $(OBJS_EC_MANAGE_PLCE) 
$(OBJS_EC_SOCKET_VIDEO) \
    $(OBJS_EC_MQTT_ANDROID) $(OBJS_EC_SQLITE) $(OBJS_EC_STORE_INFO) $(OBJS_EC_MANAGE_CAMERA) 
$(OBJS_DEAL_REQUEST_LOOP) \
    $(OBJS_PUSH_VIDEO)
                         


$(TARGET):$(OBJS)
    $(LD) -o $(OUTPUT_DIR)/$(TARGET) $(OBJS)  $(CFLAGS_OTHERS_LIB) $(LIB_FOR_SRS)  $(LINK_OPTION) 
    $(STRIP) $(OUTPUT_DIR)/$(TARGET)

$(OBJS_MAIN):
    $(CC) -c $(SRC_DIR)/main.c $(COMPILE_ALL_OPTION)
$(OBJS_EC_UART_232):
    $(CC) -c $(SRC_DIR)/ec_uart_232.c $(COMPILE_ALL_OPTION)
$(OBJS_EC_UART_485):
    $(CC) -c $(SRC_DIR)/ec_uart_485.c $(COMPILE_ALL_OPTION)
$(OBJS_EC_MANAGE_PLCE):
    $(CC) -c $(SRC_DIR)/ec_manage_plce.c $(COMPILE_ALL_OPTION)
$(OBJS_EC_SOCKET_VIDEO):
    $(CC) -c $(SRC_DIR)/ec_socket_video.c $(COMPILE_ALL_OPTION)
$(OBJS_EC_MQTT_ANDROID):
    $(CC) -c $(SRC_DIR)/ec_mqtt_android.c $(COMPILE_ALL_OPTION)
$(OBJS_EC_SQLITE):
    $(CC) -c $(SRC_DIR)/ec_sqlite.c $(COMPILE_ALL_OPTION)
$(OBJS_EC_STORE_INFO):
    $(CC) -c $(SRC_DIR)/ec_store_info.c $(COMPILE_ALL_OPTION)
$(OBJS_EC_MANAGE_CAMERA):
    $(CC) -c $(SRC_DIR)/ec_manage_camera.c $(COMPILE_ALL_OPTION)
$(OBJS_DEAL_REQUEST_LOOP):
    $(CC) -c $(SRC_DIR)/deal_request_loop.c $(COMPILE_ALL_OPTION)
$(OBJS_PUSH_VIDEO):
    $(CC) -c $(SRC_DIR)/push_video.c  $(COMPILE_ALL_OPTION)

.PHONY:clean copylib
clean:
    -$(RM) $(OUTPUT_DIR)/* $(OBJS)
copylib:
     $(CP) $(LIB_FOR_MQTT) $(SYS_LOCAL_LIB_DIR)/
     $(CP) $(LIB_FOR_JSON) $(SYS_LOCAL_LIB_DIR)/
     $(CP) $(LIB_FOR_SQLITE3) $(SYS_LOCAL_LIB_DIR)/
     $(LDCONFIG)
```

make error 1:

```
...
no errors
...
aarch64-linux-gnu-gcc -c ./src/ec_store_info.c -Wall  -Wcomment -Wformat -Wmissing-braces - 
Wswitch -Wuninitialized -Wbad-function-cast -Waggregate-return -Wmultichar -Wsign-compare - 
Wshadow
aarch64-linux-gnu-gcc -c ./src/ec_manage_camera.c -Wall  -Wcomment -Wformat -Wmissing-braces - 
Wswitch -Wuninitialized -Wbad-function-cast -Waggregate-return -Wmultichar -Wsign-compare - 
Wshadow
aarch64-linux-gnu-gcc -c ./src/deal_request_loop.c -Wall  -Wcomment -Wformat -Wmissing-braces - 
Wswitch -Wuninitialized -Wbad-function-cast -Waggregate-return -Wmultichar -Wsign-compare - 
Wshadow
aarch64-linux-gnu-gcc -c ./src/push_video.c  -Wall  -Wcomment -Wformat -Wmissing-braces -Wswitch 
-Wuninitialized -Wbad-function-cast -Waggregate-return -Wmultichar -Wsign-compare -Wshadow
./src/push_video.c: In function 'PushVideoToServer':
./src/push_video.c:21:43: warning: pointer targets in passing argument 2 of 
'srs_h264_write_raw_frames' differ in signedness [-Wpointer-sign]
 ret = srs_h264_write_raw_frames(Rtmp, data, dataSize, DTS, PTS);
                                       ^~~~
In file included from ./src/push_video.c:2:
./src/../head/srs_librtmp/srs_librtmp.h:465:12: note: expected 'char *' but argument is of type 
'unsigned char *'
extern int srs_h264_write_raw_frames(srs_rtmp_t rtmp, char* frames, int frames_size, uint32_t 
dts, uint32_t pts);
        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
./src/push_video.c: In function 'PushVideoFunction':
./src/push_video.c:86:1: warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]
}
^
aarch64-linux-gnu-ld -o ./output/ecSmartFire main.o ec_uart_232.o ec_uart_485.o ec_manage_plce.o 
ec_socket_video.o ec_mqtt_android.o ec_sqlite.o ec_store_info.o ec_manage_camera.o 
deal_request_loop.o push_video.o   ./lib/srslibrtmp_lib/*  -lpaho-mqtt3a -ljson-c -lsqlite3  -lm 
-lc -lpthread -ldl -lstdc++ -static
aarch64-linux-gnu-ld: cannot find -lstdc++
make: *** [Makefile:51: ecSmartFire] Error 1
```

make error 2:

```
...
/usr/lib/gcc-cross/aarch64-linux-gnu/8/../../../../aarch64-linux- 
gnu/bin/ld: cannot find -lpaho-mqtt3a
/usr/lib/gcc-cross/aarch64-linux-gnu/8/../../../../aarch64-linux- 
gnu/bin/ld: ./lib/srslibrtmp_lib/srs_librtmp.a(srs_lib_simple_socket.o): 
in function `srs_hijack_io_connect(void*, char const*, int)':
```

Comment: You should always use the compiler front end (`gcc`) to compile and link.  Don't use the linker (`ld`) directly unless you really know what you're doing and have special linking needs (there's virtually no reason to ever invoke the linker directly).  Second, all your code appears to be C code and you're using the C compiler, so why are you trying to link `stdc++` which is the C++ STL runtime library?

Comment: @ MadScientist yes， srs_librtmp.a\ libssl.a \libcrypto.a are c++ STL runtime library.

Comment: @MadScientist  if I always use the gcc not ld, error 2 will occur.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved it.

1,as MadScientist said, I always use *gcc* to compile not *ld*.
2,I use option ***-Wl,-Bstatic*** and ***-Wl,-Bdynamic*** to separte static library and dynamic library.

```
$(TARGET):$(OBJS)
$(CC)  -L $(LIB_FOR_SRS) -o $(OUTPUT_DIR)/$(TARGET)  $(OBJS) -Wl,-Bstatic -lssl - 
lcrypto  \
-Wl,-Bdynamic $(DYNAMIC_LINK_OPTION) $(STATIC_LINK_OPTION) 
$(STRIP) $(OUTPUT_DIR)/$(TARGET)
```